# How to print a div with the css of the page its contained in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

I have included the links to the css files in the scripts and those links work. which i checked through console log.  How do include the css in the printed file.

I have tried using media="print" on css links on the head of the page.

```
 <script>
        function printDiv() {
            var content = document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML;
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
            var bootstrap = '{{ URL::asset('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}';
            console.log(bootstrap);
            var fontAwsome = '{{ URL::asset('bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}';
            var icon = '{{ URL:: asset('bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css') }}';
            var skin = '{{ URL:: asset('dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css') }}';
            var adminLite = '{{ URL::asset('dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}';
            mywindow.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head>"+
                "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"><title>Print</title> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\""+bootstrap+"\" media=\"print\">" +
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\""+fontAwsome+"\" media=\"print\">" +
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\""+icon+"\" media=\"print\">" +
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\""+skin+"\" media=\"print\">" +
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\""+adminLite+"\" media=\"print\"></head><body >"+content+"</body></html>");
            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.focus()
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you getting the files in the variables you are storing them?

Comment: yes i am getting the files that have been stored in the project in the variables@user2507

Comment: what are you seeing in the window that opens up?

Comment: It looks like a timing issue to me. If you can confirm what you see in the window that opens up.

Comment: a plain html formatted file @user2507

Comment: Try introducing a timeout before `mywindow.document.write`. Give a timeout of about 2-3 seconds to confirm its a timing issue.

Comment: I added time out in "`mywindow.close()`" and used `onload="window.print()" `function inside the body of the  `document.write` then IT WORKED.@user2507